# How to implement a custom keyboard pop on an iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard, uitabview

I have a tabviewcontroller and within that is a navigationcontroller and tableview. When i tap on one of the table rows I want a custom keyboard to pop up. (This will be some simple plus and minus buttons to increase/decrease a counter on the tablerow item)

I'm assuming I create a View Controller and add it as a subview but how do I add it so that it pops over the tab bar?

What would be the general steps to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom Views for Data Input](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1)

Comment: Thanks. Works great except I can't set the custom keyboard height. It is set in my custom view but when I test it, it is still the standard height.

Comment: I noticed this in the docs, maybe this is your problem? "If UIKit encounters an input view with a UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight value in its autoresizing mask, it changes the height to match the keyboard."

Comment: I took off the default autoresizing options on the view and it works fine now. Thank you.